# Python item in list not working

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement

I am having an issue with an if statement regarding an item in a list. Here is the code I am using

```
score = 0
for j in range(0,1):
    for k in range(0,len(split)):
        keyword = str(split[k][1])
        words = texts[j]
        print(keyword,words)
        if str(keyword) in list(words):
            print("true")
            score = score + float(split[k][0])
        else:
            print("false")
        print(score)
```

Here is the portion of the output where the statement is visibly wrong. What is wrong in the situation?

"now"  ['anonym', 'now']
false
0

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do. What input you are providing to the code. I'm not sure I understand what that last line is supposed to be either?

Comment: split is a list of touples in this format [['0.012', '"can" '], [' 0.012', '"need" ']]. Texts is a long list of lists containing words in the form of strings like this: [['anonym', 'now'], ['greet'], ['hi']]. Last line is just the output from the print statements

Comment: Edit your question to explain the general idea of what your code is *supposed* to do. Provide the exact input you are providing in to that code, and what wrong output you are getting. Do this in your question, not in the comments. Explain what the *expected* output is. What *should* be the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `keyword` is `"now"` - INCLUDING the quote marks.  It indeed does not exist in `words`, which only includes words without quote marks.  Either fix whatever problem with the source of the data is adding those quotes, or strip them off with something like `keyword = keyword.strip('"')`.